# Calculate customer's balance by it's transactions

Tags: quickbooks

We have two .NET apps used to import customers and transactions into our db.
One is "client" app running on QB user's side another one is a small web service to interact with web connector.
We save all custmers and their "base class" transactions / changes in our DB and display on a web site. Users can see their transaction information there. Problem is that customer's balance does not always get equal to Sum(Amount) for their transactions. We already know that a customer can have a job (sub level customer) and count those transactions too. Still it appeared that a customer can get payment discounts and we needed to count that too.

What is a reliable way of counting customer's balance which always coinside with to their balance ?
I read a post about using Balance Detail Reports but I'd like not use it.

Thanks,

Vlad

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a exact answer as there's a lot of little pieces that you may be missing, we don't know how you are calculating your totals so it's just guess work here. Here's a list of the transactions that I know of that effect a customer's balance, along with some things to look for.

- Invoices can have a subtotal and sales tax which should both increase the balance.
- Receive Payments can have discounts which should also reduce the balance along with the payment amount.
- Journal Entries against Accounts Receivable for the Customer will either increase or decrease the balance depending on if it's a debit or credit to the AR account.
- Credit Memos should reduce the balance.

Keep in mind there may be more than one Accounts Receivable account, so you need to make sure you don't filter for all A/R accounts on Journal Entries.

Your best bet to figure out what you are missing is to find a customer who has a different balance than what you calculated and review your detailed transactions vs. the detailed transaction for the customer in QuickBooks.

Comment: Yes, we find cutomers who have different balances compared with sum of transactions and look it in QB. What types of transactions influence balances, should we get all types (to make it work faster) ? We donn't filter them on account. Btw, if we filter by AccountsReceivable account type then some transactions needed are not returned.

Comment: When you look in QuickBooks and compare the detail list to what you generated, what transactions are missing from you list that are in QuickBooks?

Comment: Discounts (showed as separate transactions) are missing. I have queried for ReceivePayments today and got a value of DiscountAmount. It is in AppliedToTxnRetList collection. So it looks like each "linked" or "referenced" transaction can have a DiscountAmount. I simply sum them all to get total discount for parent transaction (payment). Maybe I am not right here. Also we have problems with Check transactions, balance goes well if they were not counted. I did not investigate this case yet.

Comment: Yes, Receive Payments can have discounts which need to be removed from the balance. Checks only have an effect on the balance if the Expense account is an Accounts Receivable account.

Comment: Can I ask you some more question ? I found that we need to change sign of Amount for Journal Entries (as you listed here). Transaction query returns only one AccountRef. No both debit/credit accounts are returned. So we cannot determine if JE tran is against AR account or not. We will add/replace it with JournalEntry query. It returns set of debit/credit lines. How can I determine if a particular JE tran is against AR account ? My idea was to find if debit or credit part of a tran has a single line and compare it to AR name const. Like AR is 1 entry in debit/credit ?

Comment: Journal Entries are a bit odd in QuickBooks. Because you can have multiple lines on an journal entry, it considers the first line the 'source' line and will use that account in the general transaction query. I would suggest that you skip journal entries in the general transaction query and use the specific JournalEntry query instead. You would then need to look at all the accounts to see if it hits A/R.

Comment: Thanks, I meant getting them with JournalEntry specific query. I mean I can have more than 2 lines in a JE transaction (not 1 line is debit and 1 line is credit). A/R account must be searched/exist in a part which has a single line ? Say a tran has 10 debit lines (expense) and a single credit line. So knowing it I would compare it's credit line's account to A/R, right ?

Comment: Not always. You could have a multi-line journal entry with 10 debit lines where one of them is A/R and the credit is some other account. You need to search all lines to see if there's an A/R account and then if the value is a debit or credit, handle the amount appropriately. (Debit to A/R will increase the balance, Credit to A/R will reduce the balance). FYI, the desktop version of QuickBooks only allows one A/R line per journal entry. Online QuickBooks allows for multiple.

Comment: ok, Thanks. My work is QB Desktop, other guy's QBO, so it is his probs :)

Comment: Which of Deposit type transactions should be counted for customer's Balance? We get Deposits as Basic tran query. Deposit's account is 'Garden Creek HOA Reserve Acct 2' and users say that this transaction should not be listed. Should they be counted only when account is Accounts Receivable ?

Comment: Correct, only if it's hitting an accounts receivable account. Keep in mind that the account name might not be "Accounts Receivable" as there can be more than one AR account or the customer could have renamed it.